# R ggplot2: Reorder grouped barplot

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

I'm fairly new to R and have managed to make a grouped bar plot using ggplot2. I want to try and reorder the plot so that the plot is ordered by 'homepercent' in decreasing order.

This is the data:

```
      team      homepercent awaypercent

1     Adelaide    85          50
2     Brisbane    18           8
3     Carlton     38          17
```

etc...

This is the code which does produce a grouped barplot, just in the order of team name.

```
winpercent <- read.csv("winpercent.csv")

winpercent.m <- melt(winpercent, id.vars='team')

ggplot(winpercent.m, aes(team, value))
    +geom_bar(aes(fill=variable), width=0.4, position=position_dodge(width=0.5), stat="identity")
    +theme(legend.position = 'top', legend.title=element_blank(), axis.title.x=element_blank(), axis.title.y=element_blank())
```

Any answers would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: `aes(reorder(team, homepercent), value)` in the ggplot call

Comment: Made me lol the answer was in the title

Comment: @AkhilNair it says 'homepercent' is not found